# How to find the average of each lists in a list of lists (array)?

Tags: python, arrays

Lets say I have an array with three lists as following:

```
[(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
```

I'd like to get the average of each list in the array

```
(1+2+0)/3, (2+9+6)/3, (2+3+6)/3
```

and make it become new arraylist with only 3 integers.

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Did you mean, ``[sum(i) / len(v) for i in v]`` ??

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
num_list = [(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
average_list = list()

for item in num_list:
    average = sum(item)/len(item)
    average_list.append(average)

print(average_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
[sum(x) / len(x) for x in yourArray]
```

Comment: @Mark I made a small edit that should fix that

Comment: Was just about to make that same edit, but that seems perfect @jamylak

Answer (score 0):

```
ls=[(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
avg_ls=[]    
for i in ls:
    avg_ls.append(sum(i)//len(i))
print(avg_ls)
```

> Output:[1, 5, 3]

Comment: I'm suspicious of the average of `1, 2, 0` being `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsts=[(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(2,3,6)]
new_lst=[sum(lst)/len(lst) for lst in lsts]
print(new_lst)
```

> Output: [1.0, 5.666666666666667, 3.6666666666666665]

Or for rounding, you can use

```
new_lst=[round((sum(lst)/len(lst)),2) for lst in lsts]
print(new_lst)
```

> Output: [1.0, 5.67, 3.67]

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension

```
lst = [(1,2,0),(2,9,6),(0,3,6)]
avg = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in lst]
print (avg)
```

[1.0, 5.666666666666667, 3.0]